# Slang meaning of "pod"

Tags: meaning, slang

From Seinfeld, season 2 episode 5 ("The Apartment"):

> JERRY: Let me explain something to you.. You see, you're not normal. 
>   You're a great guy, I love you, but you're a pod.  I, on the other
>   hand, am a human being. I sometimes feel awkward, uncomfortable,  even
>   inhibited in certain situations with the other human beings. You
>   wouldn't understand.
>
> KRAMER: Because I'm a pod?

What's the meaning of "pod" here? Any reference for this / usage in this sense other than in Seinfeld?

Comment: This exact question has been answered here: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/you-are-a-pod.2223802/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll answer my own question based on the link from user "Kyle" in a comment to the original question:

Based on [this thread](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/you-are-a-pod.2223802/), discussing this exact Seinfeld episode, a "pod" here *"is a reference to the pod people from the science-fiction book (and movie) Invasion of the Body Snatchers. As Wikipedia explains, the pods were a race of extraterrestrial parasites that "floated in space like spores," occasionally landing on planets and "spawning emotionless replicas." Thus, a pod person, or "pod," looks like any other human being, but is actually an emotionless alien".*

Comment: "Pod person" is a more common form, and is found in [actual dictionaries](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pod-person), but "pod" is a humorous contraction of this.